# Vector question

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all vectors $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the second component of $u$ is $12e_2$ and $\mid\mid u \mid\mid= 13$.

Any ideas how to go about starting this problem?

Comment: Let u = (x, 12)... What can x be?

Comment: I don’t understand why this question has received downvotes. The OP is merely asking for an idea on how to *start* the problem. Yes, G Muf obviously hasn’t shared any personal thoughts, but I’m going to infer that’s because s/he is clueless on where to begin.

Comment: Nevertheless, @GMuf, please include as much context as you can; for example, try sharing whence this problem came or what you’re currently studying.

Comment: Yes sorry next time I will try to be more descriptive, and yes I had no idea where to start!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint, assuming $e_2$ is the standard basis vector $(0, 1)$: Try solving the equation $x^2 + 12^2 = 13^2$. A known Pythagorean triple pops out of this, and you have your answers.